# Look up for dictionary terms in a Series of lists, then return the Key

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, series

I've imported a spreadsheet I'd exported from Linkedin of my connections and want to categorize people's positions at different  levels.

So, I've created a dictionary with the terms to look up each position level.

A first version of the dictionary would be:

```
dicpositions = {'0 - CEO, Founder': ['CEO', 'Founder', 'Co-Founder', 'Cofounder', 'Owner'],
                '1 - Director of': ['Director', 'Head'], 
                '2 - Manager': ['Manager', 'Administrador'], 
                '3 - Engenheiro': ['Engenheiro', 'Engineering'], 
                '4 - Consultor': ['Consultor', 'Consultant'], 
                '5 - Estagiário': ['Estagiário', 'Intern'], 
                '6 - Desempregado': ['Self-Employed', 'Autônomo'], 
                '7 - Professor': ['Professor', 'Researcher'] }
```

And I need a code to read each position in my spreadsheet, check if there is any of these terms and return the equivalent key in another specific column.

A sample data of the dataframe i'm reading would be:

```
sample = pd.Series(data = (['(blank)'], ['Estagiário'], ['Professor', 'Adjunto'], 
                           ['CEO', 'and', 'Founder'], ['Engenheiro', 'de', 'Produção'], 
                           ['Consultant'], ['Founder', 'and', 'CTO'], 
                           ['Intern'], ['Manager', 'Specialist'], 
                           ['Administrador', 'de', 'Novos', 'Negócios'], 
                           ['Administrador', 'de', 'Serviços']))
```

Which Returns:

```
0                                [(blank)]
1                             [Estagiário]
2                     [Professor, Adjunto]
3                      [CEO, and, Founder]
4               [Engenheiro, de, Produção]
5                             [Consultant]
6                      [Founder, and, CTO]
7                                 [Intern]
8                    [Manager, Specialist]
9     [Administrador, de, Novos, Negócios]
10           [Administrador, de, Serviços]
dtype: object
```

It's a Series of lists I get when I write:

```
plan['Position'].str.split()
```

I've done the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
plan = pd.read_excel('SpreadSheet Name.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Positions')

list0 = ['CEO', 'Founder', 'Co-Founder', 'Cofounder', 'Owner']
list1 = ['Director', 'Head']
list2 = ['Manager', 'Administrador']   
listgeral = [dic0, dic1, dic2]

def in_list(list_to_search,terms_to_search):     
    results = [item for item in list_to_search if item in terms_to_search]
    if len(results) > 0:
        return '0 - CEO, Founder'        
    else:
        pass
plan['PositionLevel'] = plan['Position'].str.split().apply(lambda x: in_list(x, listgeral[0]))
```

Actual output:

```
                                          Position           PositionLevel
0                                        '(blank)'                None
1                                     'Estagiário'                None
2                              'Professor Adjunto'                None
3                                'CEO and Founder'         '0 - CEO, Founder'
4                         'Engenheiro de produção'                None
5                                     'Consultant'                None
6                                'Founder and CTO'         '0 - CEO, Founder'
7                                         'Intern'                None
8                             'Manager Specialist'                None
9                'Administrador de Novos Negócios'                None
```

Expected output:

```
                                            Position         PositionLevel
0                                          '(blank)'              None
1                                       'Estagiário'       '5 - Estagiário'
2                                'Professor Adjunto'       '7 - Professor'
3                                  'CEO and Founder'      '0 - CEO, Founder'
4                           'Engenheiro de produção'       '3 - Engenheiro'
5                                       'Consultant'       '4 - Consultor'
6                                  'Founder and CTO'      '0 - CEO, Founder'
7                                           'Intern'       '5 - Estagiário'
8                               'Manager Specialist'        '2 - Manager'
9                  'Administrador de Novos Negócios'        '2 - Manager'
```

First I was planning to run that code for every list inside my `listgeral`, but I coundn't do so. Then I started to believe it would be better to apply this one for a big dictionary, just as the `dicpositions` from the beginning of the question, and the return the key of the term.

I've tried to apply the following code to this program:

```
dictest = {'0 - CEO, Founder': ['CEO', 'Founder', 'Co-Founder', 'Cofounder', 'Owner'], 
           '1 - Director of': ['Director', 'Head'], 
           '2 - Manager': ['Manager', 'Administrador']}

def in_dic (x, dictest):
    for key in dictest:
        for elem in dictest[key]:
            if elem == x:
                return key
    return False
```

Where the output from:
    `in_dic('CEO', dictest)`

Is
    `'0 - CEO, Founder'`

But I couldn't advance from it and apply this function `in_dic()` to my problem.

I would really appreciate anybody's help.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please provide at least some sample data (see [mcve]).

Comment: Hey, AMC, thank you for the feedback, I've just some sample data and also the output I want and the output I have! Hope that it helps! Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dicgeral_2 = {'0 - Teste': ['Accelerator', 'Account'], '1 - Teste': ['Académico'], '2 - Teste': ['Visual', 'Volunteer']}

def in_dict(pos, dic):
    for key, value in dic.items():
        if pos in value:
            return key
    return False

in_dict("Account", dicgeral_2)
```

Output:

```
>>0 - Teste
```

Comment: Heym Errol, thank you for answering me. So, this is great to find the key given an element. Although, I would like to find it given a serie of lists. 

In my case the serie of lists code is ```plan['Positions'].str.split()```. 

Where the output is:

```0                                               [(blank)]
1                                             [Académico]
2                         [Accelerator, Program, Manager]
3                                  [Account, Coordinator]
4                                      [Account, Manager]
                              ...```

Thx!

Comment: Hi, Sorry. Can you edit your question. Provide some sample data, and expected output.

Comment: Hey, you're right! I've tried to make it easier to understand, putting the output I got, the output I want and a sample data! Hope that it helps! Thx a lot!